# Can you partially bind a 0-ary function in Scala?

Tags: scala

I was trying to create a function pointer like:

```
def foo(a: String): Unit = { println(s"a = $a") }

val parameter = "some parameter"
// Here I'd want something like foo(parameter) _, but that doesn't work.
val partialFooWithParameter: () => Unit = ???
```

Is there something I could replace the `???` with that would work, or is this just not possible in Scala?

**Update**: Seems like the answer is No.

Best solutions is a function literal:

```
def partialFooWithParameter: () => Unit = () => foo(parameter)
```

Although it's still not a partially-applied function:

```
def bar(a: String, b: String): String = a + b
// Partially-applied.
val partial: (String => String) = bar("a", _)
// Function literal.
val literal: (String => String) = b => bar("a", b)
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything better than `val partialFooWithParameter: () => String = () => foo(parameter)`.

Comment: What would the point be? Delay execution?

Comment: A few situations I can think of - function with side-effect; passing in a factory method for unit testing; property-style alias to lookup values in a dynamic map.

Comment: What's the error you're getting when you try the proposed `foo(parameter)`?

Comment: @Bergi - `error: _ must follow method; cannot follow Unit`. The function gets executed.

Comment: @jkinkead: Why are you using `_` at all?

Comment: My understanding: The OP wants that when partialFooWIthParameter is evaluated it returns the value foo(parameter). But he doesn't want it evaluated yet, only on demand. Although "lazy val" would seem to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. Some of your types are incorrect.

```
def foo(a: String): Unit = { println(s"a = $a") }

val parameter = "some parameter"
// Here I'd want something like foo(parameter) _, but that doesn't work.
def partialFooWithParameter: () => Unit = () => foo(parameter)
```

Comment: This gets what I want, but it's not a partial. Compare: `def bar(a: String, b: String): String = { s"a=$a, b=$b" }
/* Partially-applied */
bar("value", _: String)
/* New function. */
(b: String) => bar("value", b)`

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you are looking for in terms of a partial. if you have val x = partialFooWithParameter the type of x will be () => Unit which is a function taking 0 arguments and returning nothing. That has to be the type if you bind the one argument to foo.

Comment: A partial function is a syntactic shorthand for a function literal; you can expand any partially-applied function into an equivalent function literal. The question is: Can you create a partially-applied function for a function that takes no arguments? I think the answer is, No. :)